# How to have the name of 2 institutes in the title page in this Beamer TeX?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

In this Beamer file, I need in the title page to have both my own institute name and the name of the institute at which I am presenting. Something like [this](http://www.stephanhartmann.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/TorontoVDT.pdf) one. Also, as in the footline I have both my name and the title and the date, I don't want them to be changed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}    

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}{}
% Class options include: notes, handout, trans
%



\title{Title}    % Enter your title between curly braces
\subtitle{}
\author{author name}                 % Enter your name between curly braces
\institute{My Institute Name Researcher}      % Enter your institute name between curly braces

\date{June 2018}                    % Enter the date or \today between curly braces

 \mode<presentation>{}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE does not compile nor does it show a title page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}    

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}{}
% Class options include: notes, handout, trans
%



\title{Title}    % Enter your title between curly braces
\subtitle{}
\author{author name}                 % Enter your name between curly braces
\institute{My Institute Name Researcher\\[0.5cm] visting Institute}      % Enter your institute name between curly braces

\date{June 2018}                    % Enter the date or \today between curly braces

 \mode<presentation>{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```